# Can a local notification not be triggered when app is in foreground?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I have a local notification that is triggered based on a date. When this notification is triggered I do some action.

The way I do it right now is this way:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    switch response.actionIdentifier {
    case UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier:
        print("Dismiss Action")
    case UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier:
        print("Default")
        // Do Action Here
    case "Snooze":
        print("Snooze")
    case "Delete":
        print("Delete")
    default:
        print("Unknown action")
    }

    completionHandler()
}
```

This is called when I take action on the notification that appears on my screen.

What I would like is, if I am inside the app the notification should not appear and perform my task automatically.

Is this possible ?

Right now my task is performed only when pressing on the notification received. I don't think it makes much sense if I am inside the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `userNotificationCenter:willPresent` delegate method of `UNUserNotificationCenter` and pass empty array as options to don't display notification.

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    // Use this to avoid notification to appear on screen
    completionHandler([])

    // Use this to dispaly notification
    completionHandler([UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert, .sound, .badge])
}
```